# Api Driven Implementation in Express js

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to nodejs / Express js, I am working on project which has frontend , Backend and Restfull Api's. All this has been developed using single Application by using domain routing.
Basically i want implementate the project all based on api and Frontend and backend will internally call the API.
Basically i want implementation something like dingo in laravel. Which actually does the same thing .i.e Api Driven. 
Ref: https://github.com/dingo/api.

I tried to find such implementation in express js but couldn't found any such a package.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: There is [restify](http://restify.com/)

Comment: Restify is purely based for restfull api, I need to run single application which contains frontend, backend and api

Comment: So you're looking for a full stack framework (Dingo is API only like Restify). There are quite few, the most popular are: [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/), [MEAN.js](http://meanjs.org/), [MEAN.io](http://mean.io/), [SailJS](http://sailsjs.org/features).

Comment: No, Dingo is package which helps us to create API and Call Api Internally, Basically i also want a package which does the similar things in node